# How can I view Azure logfiles when running locally?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'd like to view the logfile from an Azure worker role which uses this:

```
RoleManager.WriteToLog("Information", "Worker Process entry point called.")
```

I'm running in the local development fabric.  Where will the above output be sent?

EDIT: I just now found [this question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360767/rolemanager-writetolog-in-azure-development-fabric), but without a satisfatory answer as of yet.

Comment: Another approach (which does not exactly address your question) consists of using a custom logger that happens to provide a proper a built-in log viewer. You can check our O/C mapper (object to cloud) at http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

http://blog.benday.com/archive/2008/11/07/23201.aspx